# Setting corner radius on alertDialog using Builder. Android

Tags: android, xml, android-alertdialog

I need to set rounded corners on an AlertDialog but specifically using a Builder.

Is it possible to set my own layout?

when using builder.setview(R.layout.my_style) i get a crash.

Comment: Possible you can set styles

Comment: when using builder.setview(r.layout.my_style) i get a crash.. is there a way around this or am I gong about this wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have added Style in layout so its crashed.
It should be

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this, R.style.my_style);
LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();
View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.xml_ui_file, null);//Add your XML File name
dialogBuilder.setView(dialogView);
  AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
alertDialog.show();
```